# Finding a list of table names in the Oracle table DBA_SOURCE

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find a list of tables in a procedure that match a list of target tables. These tables all contain a same named column. Anyway, I've tried two queries with no luck. Here they are

```
select atc.TABLE_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLS atc join  all_SOURCE als on atc.table_name
 like '%'||als.text||'%' and als.name = 'SP_SLD_GEN_GIC_REINV_DET_FI' where
atc.COLUMN_NAME = 'C_CURR';

select atc.TABLE_NAME 
from ALL_TAB_COLS atc where atc.COLUMN_NAME = 'C_CURR'
and atc.table_name like (select '%'||als.text||'%' from all_SOURCE als
where als.name = 'SP_SLD_GEN_REINV_DET_FI')
order by atc.TABLE_NAME;
```

Neither returns anything. What I want is a list of all the tables found in Source from the procedure 'SP_SLD_GEN_REINV_DET_FI', containing table names that match the list of tables names from ALL_TAB_COLS where containing the column named 'C_CURR'.

I know when you use 'like' your usually comparing to a hard string like '%AUTUMN%'. Here, you can see I'm trying to embed the returned string in a set of '%' to complement using 'LIKE'. I'm not getting it.  Is there a way to do this.

Or can I do this using ISNTR()?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using `dba_source` rather than `dba_dependencies`?  Normally, you could just look at `dba_dependencies` to see which tables a procedure is dependent on.  You might have to resort to querying the source code, though, if you have runtime dependencies via dynamic SQL but that is, hopefully, unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

Used DBA_DEPENDANCIES instead. This works. See below:

```
select TABLE_NAME
    from ALL_TAB_COLS where COLUMN_NAME = 'C_CURR'
    and table_name in (
    select referenced_name
    from   SYS.DBA_dependencies
    where  referenced_type = 'TABLE'
    and    referenced_owner = 'SLDPROD'
    and    name in ('SP_SLD_GEN_GIC_REINV_DET_FI')
    );
```